# ResponsiveFilemanager won't upload files

Tags: javascript, php, plugins

I'm trying to use this plugin. Everythings work fine, only uploading files won't work. I can create folders, create new files, but if i try to upload any file, it shows me that file is successful uploaded and there is no file.

http://screenshot.cz/HPQH1/

Have you any experience with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with it too, but changing the path configuration in `..\filemanager\config\config.php` to your server specific setup is probably key. On a server setup with a site root of e.g. `/httpdocs` you may end up with something like this:

```
$base_url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'';
$upload_dir = '/source/images/';   // path from base_url to base of upload folder (with start and final /)
$current_path = '../../../../source/images/';    // relative path from filemanager folder to upload folder (with final /)
$thumbs_base_path = '../../../../source/thumbs/';   // relative path from filemanager folder to thumbs folder (with final /)
```

Comment: i have this one settings
$base_url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'';
$upload_dir = '/source/';   // path from base_url to base of upload folder (with start and final /)
$current_path = '../../source/';    // relative path from filemanager folder to upload folder (with final /)
$thumbs_base_path = '../../source/thumbs/';   // relative path from filemanager folder to thumbs folder (with final /)

interesting is that making files and folders work perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same problem. I could create files and folders but not upload files. It turned out that it didn't had anything to do with the `config.php`. The problem for me was that when I uploaded the files to the server with ftp, the `../filemanager/upload.php` got corrupted.

It happened every time I uploaded this file. No other file had any problem. By setting the ftp protocol to sftp, it got uploaded correctly and then the plugin worked perfectly. So if anyone has the same problem, take a look at the `upload.php` and see if it's corrupted.